# Passing attributes for directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm fairly new in the world of AngularJS and now I ran into a problem I couldn't solve by myself (with Google on my left hand).

I've created a directive, such as:

```
.directive('customerTableRow', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            column: '=column',
            key: '@key',
            label: '@label',
            value: '=value'
        },
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html'
    }
})
```

And I use it in view like this:

```
<customer-table-row column="column" key="some_key" label="Some Key" value="table.some_key"></customer-table-row>
```

I use this inside another directive, where I pass "column" and a JSON object from database, into variable "table", which I can use inside view like `{{column}}` and `{{table.id}}`.

This works as intended, but I would like to pass "value" attribute into my directive so that it would be like `value: '=table.key'`. I'd like to modify my directive so that I could pass this `key` only once, which would be passed into "key" as "@key" and into "value" so that it would contain "table.key" value, so that I could call my directive like:

```
<customer-table-row column="column" key="some_key" label="Some Key"></customer-table-row>
```

Or the opposite, like:

```
<customer-table-row column="column" label="Some Key" value="table.some_key"></customer-table-row>
```

..and this directive would get the index of "some_key" from the "value" attribute.

Can this be done at all and if so, what should I modify?

If this was a javascript function, I would do it something like this:

```
var table = {some_key: 'this is table.some_key value'};

function customerTableRow(column, key, label) {
    return {
        column: column,
        key: key,
        label: label,
        value: eval('table.'+key)
    };
}

customerTableRow('some_column', 'some_key', 'Label for row');
```

Which outputs:

```
Object {
    column: "some_column",
    key: "some_key",
    label: "Label for row",
    value: "this is table.some_key value"
}
```

**EDIT:**
The "table" in this `value: '=table.key'` can be hard coded, it doesn't need to be inherited from parent scope or anything fancy. If only I could determine the "key" once and use it to pass both "key" and "value" parameters for this directive.

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved it. I had to add `transclude: true,` into my directive, create a link function and there I did the following:

```
scope.value = (eval('scope.$parent.table.'+scope.key) != '' ? eval('scope.$parent.table.'+scope.key) : '');
```

Might not be the best way to do this, but at least its a workaround.